# Why does Cypress print `cy.log` output later than I would expect?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to use `cy.log` to help me understand why a test is failing. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to log the messages I want. After fiddling around for a bit I resorted to this test:

```js
describe.only("In what order are these messages printed?", () => {
  it("I would expect the LOG to be printed before the EXPECT", () => {
    cy.log("Hello from cy.log");
    expect(1 + 1).to.equal(2);
  });
});
```

I expect the "Hello" to appear first, but what I get is this:

[image]

Moreover, in a failing test, the `cy.log` does not seem to appear at all, which is unfortunate for me. Again, here is a simple but extreme example.

```js
describe.only("Here is my real problem", () => {
  it("I would expect the LOG to be printed before the test fails", () => {
    cy.log("Hello from cy.log");
    expect(2 + 2).to.equal(42);
  });
});
```

This produces this:

[image]

#### Is this expected behaviour in Cypress?

If so, I could resort to `console.log`. Although it is a shame we can't neatly report the log in the main Cypress window itself.

Or have I accidentally set a setting that messes up timing of `cy.log`?

#### Update: *Summary from answers*

There are excellent answers below. The key is to realise that when you write a Cypress test like this:

```
it("...",()=>{
   callFunctionA()
   b += 1;
   cy.log("Hello from line C")
   d = 10;
   cy.get("#input-box-e")
   console.log("f")
})
```

... what *actually* happens is:

```
   callFunctionA()
   b += 1;
   Add to list to do LATER: cy.log("Hello from line C")
   d = 10;
   Add to list to do LATER: cy.get("#input-box-e")
   console.log("f")
```

Why? I think it is because Cypress was designed specifically to *interact with web pages*. The overwhelming priority is therefore to queue up the `cy.get()` commands, and retry them until they time-out, etc. That is *so* important that the makers of Cypress are willing (and indeed forced) to subvert our naive expectations of what an apparently synchronous list of code statements mean.

Only by pushing the `cy.get` commands into a queue where they can be tried and retried, can the web page engagement work so well.

I assume `cy.log` was added into the set of things that get added to that queue, simply because it is part of `cy.`.

#### Explanation of the behaviour I saw

I think what was happening in my cases above is that the `expect` is, effectively, plain Javascript (not a thing dangling off `cy.`), and so it was executed first, while the `cy.log` was pushed into a queue to do later.

When the expect was successful, the `cy.log` eventually printed.

When the expect failed, that aborted the queue of `cy.` commands for that test, so the `cy.log` never printed.

#### Solution

So yes, if we want to log output *immediately* and *not* conditionally on the test passing, we should use `console.log` not `cy.log`.

Or we can delay the testing to occur inside the `cy.` queue, using `cy.then()`, as shown by @Fody.

Comment: Solutions go in answers, not in edits to the question. If you have a solution, please add it as an answer below, instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cypress uses a queue system, basically anything `cy.*` is an instruction to add something to the command queue.

When the test code is run, everything is executed sequentially as per normal javascript, ***except*** the command queue is run after the test code has executed.

You can put synchronous javascript on the queue with `cy.then()`, and get the log order as per the command queue.

```js
describe.only("Here is my real problem", () => {
  it("I would expect the LOG to be printed before the test fails", () => {
    cy.log("Hello from cy.log");
    cy.then(() => expect(2 + 2).to.equal(42))
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation. The key is that **Everything other than `cy.*` is executed in normal order**, and then the `cy.*` stuff happens via a queue. I never realised that explicitly until you pointed it out.

Comment: There is no such command `cy.then` , `then` is chainable. `Cy.log("something").then(() => {console.log('something else after')})`

Comment: If you try it you will be surprised :)

Answer (score 2):

Cypress commands are async, they get put onto a queue and run seperately from your other code.

If you want to run code sequentially alongside the cypress commands, you can put the synchronous code inside a .then() method appended to the end of the cypress command.

If you check out this, it should explain how async queuing of cypress commands works: https://learn.cypress.io/cypress-fundamentals/understanding-the-asynchronous-nature-of-cypress

Comment: Thank you! I have read that before but I must have not really understood it - thank you for pointing it out.