# Why assignment operator executes before the previously declared action?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

There is a code like

```
let someGlobalVariable = undefined;

describe('Test description', () => {
    it('Should init global variable after action 2', () => {
        action1() // returns Chainable object
            .then(() => {
                // actions like 'cy.xpath('myXpath').click()' (action2)
                someGlobalVariable = 'some value';
                console.log('someGlobalVariable initialized');
            });
    });
})
```

When this code is executed, the assignment and the log output to the console is done immediately after the completion of action1, but before action2 (which seems to be synchronous). If something goes wrong in action2 and it fails, the global variable is already initialized, which should not be the case. I assume that such execution through some kind of performance optimizations of Cypress. Is this true and how to fix/disable it?

I'm using cypress 12.13.0.

Answer (score 5):

See the excellent question [Why does Cypress print `cy.log` output later than I would expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76213928/21264423)

Commands are added to a queue, and the queue runs *later* than the Javascript variable assignment inside the test.

But you can defer the assignment by adding it to the queue.

```js
let someGlobalVariable = undefined;

describe('Test description', () => {
    it('Should init global variable after action 2', () => {
        action1() // returns Chainable object
            .then(() => {
                // actions like 'cy.xpath('myXpath').click()' (action2)

                // add this to the queue
                cy.then(() => {
                  someGlobalVariable = 'some value';
                  console.log('someGlobalVariable initialized');
                })

            });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Cypress commands are asynchronous, whereas your variable assignment and `console.log` are synchronous. Specifically, in this case, it means that the variable assignment will not wait for your Cypress command to complete before executing. [Cypress has documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Commands-Are-Asynchronous) explaining that their commands are asynchronous and [how to use the commands with synchronous code.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Mixing-Async-and-Sync-code) Here is some documentation on how JavaScript handles [synchronous vs. asynchronous commands.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-in-javascript/) (Ignore the parts about Promises when thinking about Cypress, [as Cypress commands are not Promises.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#The-Cypress-Command-Queue))

In your example, you'd need to have separate `.then()` blocks for `action2()` and your synchronous code. Or, if `action1()` is chainable, you could chain `action2()` off of `action1()`, and then use the `.then()` block.

```js
// Separate blocks
action1().then(() => {
  action2().then(() => {
    someGlobalVariable = 'some value';
    console.log('someGlobalVariable initialized');
  });
});

// if action1() is chainable
action1().action2().then(() => {
  someGlobalVariable = 'some value';
  console.log('someGlobalVariable initialized');
});
```