# Cypress cy.request response store in record type typescript

Tags: typescript, command, cypress

I'm working on some Cypress tests where I need to add some information to a database via an api call. But I need all the IDs from the response to pass to another request within Cypress but I need to do it outside the for loop as I don't want to make the request everytime we have information. I've created a record type and added a value within the .then but it is still undefined. The parameter within the submitRequest call is undefined. Has anyone come across this before? I can't call the submitRequest method within the cy.request then body as it has to be outside the for loop. Below is the code

````
    let idsWithValue: Record<string, commonType.Information>;
    
    for (let index in information) {
        //Create the request
        const requestBody = {
            name: `information.Name`,
            description: `information.Description`
        }


        //Send request for elements
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url,
            body: requestBody,
            headers: coApi.getRequestHeaders()
        }

        cy.request(options).then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
            const informationId: string = response.body;
            //After we get the informationId from server add it to a list to pass to another request method
            idsWithValue[informationId] =information[index];
           
        })
    }

    //Submit  request (idsWithValueis undefined here) this has to be outside for loop
    submitRequest(idsWithValue);```
````

Comment: Where does `elementIdsWithValue` come from? And `templateInformation`? They aren't created within the loop, so what is the problem?

Comment: Is `idsWithValue` supposed to be the `elementIdsWithValue` parameter? No wonder it's undefined, you would need to use the same variable name.

Comment: Sorry copy and paste error. I've just edited the post

Comment: I would also ask why is the request in the loop, because it looks like it's the same request each time. Is the strings inside `requestBody` supposed to come from `information` variable, because that would not be the correct syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Cypress print \`cy.log\` output later than I would expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213898/why-does-cypress-print-cy-log-output-later-than-i-would-expect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fix it by making sure you only call `submitRequest()` after all `cy.request()` in the loop have completed.

Try wrapping the call in a `cy.then()`, I'm not 100% sure without running a test but usually Cypress won't execute a command until all the previous commands are finished,

```js
const idsWithValue = [];
for (...) {
  cy.request(...).then(response => {
    idsWithValue[...] = ...
  })
}

cy.then(() => {
  submitRequest(idsWithValue)
})
```