# cypress .each() does not pause on cy.wait

Tags: testing, web, cypress, cypress-intercept

shouldn't cypress wait between iterations if there is cy.wait() or setTimeout in there?

```
describe("Store", () => {
    it("changes category on click", () => {
        cy.visit("/store");
        cy.intercept("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/*").as(
            "getProducts",
        );
        cy.get(".category").each((category, i, l) => {
            category.click();
            cy.wait("@getProducts");
            console.log(i);
        });
    });
});
```

but when I run this all the buttons are getting called, it's not waiting for the API call

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm3So.png)

Comment: by putting the category.click() inside a cy.then() solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.each()` *does* pause for `cy.wait()` inside the loop, but the `console.log()` does not.

All the `cy` commands you have in the test are run separately on a queue, but javascript code like `console.log` are executed immediately.

To see the difference, execute the `console.log` on the queue like this

```js
cy.get(".category").each((category, i) => {
  category.click()
  cy.wait("@getProducts")
  cy.then(() => console.log(i))   // console.log on the queue in sync with other cy.* 
})
```

Here's my dev-tools console, the app and the test are in sync:

[image]

See also [Why does Cypress print `cy.log` output later than I would expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213898/why-does-cypress-print-cy-log-output-later-than-i-would-expect)