# How to reassign variable inside if-else statement in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I have JS function in my Cypress test that should work in 2 modes: create new item or edit existing item if it already exists. Something like this:

```
let editMode = true
cy.get('body').then(($body) => { 
  if ($body.find("tr:contains('No data to display')").is(':visible')) {
    editMode = false // Here is the point where re-assining should happen if the item was not found
    // Do something in Create mode
  } else {
    // do something in Edit mode
  }
})

... // Some code common for the both modes is here

// Specific create/edit code
if (editMode === false) {
  // do something in Create mode // Expect to have this code executed
} else {
  // do something in Edit mode // But this code is actually executed
}
```

As you can see from the comments above, in my code reassigning doesn't work. Could you, please point me the reason?

Comment: You'll need to put the logic that relies on `editMode` inside of your `.then()` callback, or `await` the `cy.get()` promise (see links above your question for more details)

Comment: `cy.get()` does not return a promise, you can't `await` it.

Comment: Since you have `// Some code common for the both modes is here`, start another `then` block with  `cy.then(() => { // Specific create/edit code ... })`.

Comment: See [Why does Cypress print `cy.log` output later than I would expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76213928/16791505) for the true reason.